# Do I need two attribute classes

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

Let's say I have an `attribute` like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public sealed class LearnAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string FailMessage;
}
```

Is it possible to define its target in a way that optional ones such as `FailMessage` are **ONLY** applicable to `property level` for a `class` that I will be decorating it with  and `LearnAttribute` itsself only applicable to `class` level?
or would I need to define two attribute classes?

So for example I could have something like this:

```
[Learn]
public class Foo
{
    [FailMessage]
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }

    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(Method1));
    }


}
```

Comment: _"that optional ones"_ - optional ones what? Properties/fields? You want user to be able to specify `LearnAttribute.FailMessage`  only when attribute is applied to property?

Comment: @GuruStron Optional attributes such as FailMessage . If we define it in the constructor of that class it will become a required attribute.

Comment: @GuruStron : Yes exactly this: "You want user to be able to specify LearnAttribute.FailMessage only when attribute is applied to property?"

Comment: _"Optional attributes such as FailMessage"_ - it is not an attribute, it is a property of attribute class, hence you can use it only when and where you are using attribute itself.

Comment: @GuruStron I see. Makes sense.  OK So the answer sadly is I need two attribute classes.

Comment: Check the update to answer - if needed you can place the attributes into hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to define its target in a way that optional ones such as `FailMessage` are ONLY applicable to property level for a class that I will be decorating it with and `LearnAttribute` itself only applicable to class level?

No. You can define target only for the attribute class itself so all it's corresponding properties/fields are accessible when it is used. If you really want to you can write a [Roslyn analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022) which will do what is needed but I think that this would be a quite confusing API, so I would recommend to stick to the more idiomatic approach with 2 different attributes.

You can create an attribute hierarchy if needed:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class LearnAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class LearnWithFailMessageAttribute : LearnAttribute
{
    public string FailMessage;
}

[Learn]
// [LearnWithFailMessage] // will not compile
public class Foo1
{
    [LearnWithFailMessage(FailMessage = "")]
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }

    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(Method1));
    }
}
```

And the `LearnWithFailMessage` will be accessible by the base class type also:

```cs
var propertyInfo = typeof(Foo1).GetProperty(nameof(Foo1.BuildingName));
var customAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<LearnAttribute>();
Console.WriteLine(customAttribute.GetType().Name); // prints "LearnWithFailMessageAttribute"
```

Though note that working with attribute hierarchies can have some quirks - see for example [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/88473).

Comment: OH thanks,  great idea.  I keep this in mind. Might end up doing it this way.